# mangen adds 'Bundle-ManifestVersion: 1' to manifest, but felix doesn't seem to accept value 1

Tags: java, osgi, manifest.mf, apache-felix

I've used 'Mangen' to process my jar, which works but it adds the next line to the manifest

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 1
```

after which Felix 1.8.0 complains with

```
-> install file:D:/bundles/osgi_ds_1.jar.new.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unknown 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:56)
```

If I change the version manually to 2, Felix does install without error.
But even if the manifest already contained Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2, mangen changes it to 1

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mangen](http://oscar-osgi.sourceforge.net/mangen/)  tool you refer to seems to be a bit outdated (last release in June 2005).

I would suggest that you try to use [Bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd) tool written by Peter Kriens instead. It serves for automatic generation of OSGi bundle manifests as well. It's also integrated into a Maven plugin -- see [Bundle Plugin for Maven](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).