# How to disable karaf-maven-plugin 4 tight dependency constraint checks

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf

Currently I am moving from karaf 3.0.5 to the newest version 4.0.2, I do assembly my own karaf with the karaf-maven-plugin. This is how my pom looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>my.own.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>assemble</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>karaf-customize</artifactId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <type>kar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.karaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-cxf</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.own.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>kar-archive</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.own.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>karaf-branding</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alutam</groupId>
        <artifactId>ziputils</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${karaf.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <javase>1.8</javase>
                <bootFeatures>
                    <feature>jasypt-encryption</feature>
                    <feature>config</feature>
                    <feature>standard</feature>
                    <feature>region</feature>
                    <feature>management</feature>
                    <feature>bundle</feature>
                    <feature>package</feature>
                    <feature>kar</feature>
                    <feature>ssh</feature>
                    <feature>http</feature>
                    <feature>cxf</feature>
                    <feature>service-wrapper</feature>
                    <feature>jdbc</feature>
                    <feature>system</feature>
                </bootFeatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

With this configuration I do get the following error for several dependencies.

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.resolver.ResourceBuilder.doBuild(ResourceBuilder.java:88)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.resolver.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:78)
```

I guess it happens within this [parser](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/framework/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/framework/util/manifestparser/ManifestParser.java). The reason is some old [third party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244226/mangen-adds-bundle-manifestversion-1-to-manifest-but-felix-doesnt-seem-to-a) libraries have only `Bundle-ManifestVersion: 1` set within their manifest file.
With karaf-maven-plugin 3.x this didn't matter at all. In contrast the karaf-maven-plugin 4.x fails with message above.
The only way I know to fix this is either rebuild from source or [repack](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/escapek/Create_OSGi_bundle_from_regular_jar_archive) the hole jar again.

Is there any other way like a configuration for the karaf-maven-plugin to disable this constraint check? Because it would be awful lot of work to get all of this bundles up an running, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same error when updating to Karaf 4 and you have two choices:

**Osgify conflictive dependency using bndtools:**

1. [Download bnd tools](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/bnd/2.4.0/bnd-2.4.0.jar)
2. Open a shell where you have downloaded bnd-2.4.0.jar.
3. Type:
   java -jar bnd-2.4.0.jar wrap -o osgify-dependency.jar dependency.jar
   where dependency.jar is your third party and osgify-dependency.jar will be the output.
4. Deploy to maven repo overriding the previous maven coordinates, or deploy your thirdparty with different coordinates.

   mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile osgify-dependency.jar ..

**Enable the wrap protocol**

Add to you maven karaf plugin wrap and wrapper features.

So you can use wrap protocol to fix your corrupted MANIFEST.MF

Inside some karaf features:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:group.id/third.party.artefact.id/version</bundle>
```

Inside your pom.xml notice feature wrap / wrapper.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
    </executions>
    <configuration>

     <!-- no startupFeatures -->
     <bootFeatures>
      <feature>feature</feature>
      <feature>jaas</feature>
      <feature>shell</feature>
      <feature>ssh</feature>
      <feature>management</feature>
      <feature>bundle</feature>
      <feature>config</feature>
      <feature>deployer</feature>
      <feature>diagnostic</feature>
      <feature>instance</feature>
      <feature>kar</feature>
      <feature>log</feature>
      <feature>package</feature>
      <feature>service</feature>
      <feature>system</feature>
      <feature>wrap</feature>
      <feature>aries-blueprint</feature>
     </bootFeatures>
     <installedFeatures>
      ..
      <feature>wrapper</feature>
     </installedFeatures>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Here you have the full code where i tested:

https://github.com/antoniomaria/gazpachoquest/blob/master/karaf-assembly/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think wrap and wrapper are two complete different features. Wrapper enable me to let karaf run as a service. Before karaf4 this was called service-wrapper. And yes I used the wrap feature, too to fix this. Also I have to mention, that I removed my maven parent. Because in may case this provided a lot of unnecessary dependencies I didn't need in my karaf deployment.

Comment: You are absolutely right, wrap and wrapper are two complete different things i just messed them up. But nice that we came up with the same solution.